# move asp.net web site from pc to server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I finished my asp.net website ,I am using vs 2013 and sql data base  I designed the web site on my pc and it is work on IIS 7 , now I want to move the web site to our server  which include  Sql server 2008 .for my database no problem I will move it .but now any thing required to move the web site to the server, I do not know if I need to install vs 2013 on the server??
*note:the web site include report viewer .

Comment: You don't need to install the visual studio on the server machine to deploy the application.

Comment: You mean just copy the web site  folder to the server and run it on IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need Visual studio for deployment but you need .NET Framework installed in the remote server.  You need to have Internet Information Services installed and it is advisable to have web deployment tools.  In large scale enterprise applications we do not use manual web deployment but it should be automated with MSBUILD.  Have a look at `[Deployment automation][1]`.  You can deploy your code to a remote server and have a look at [Remote Deployment](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-remote-agent).

Comment: Yes IIS. it is already installed on the server and .net framework  4.5

Comment: Good to go!! install dotnet framework.  None of my build servers have visual studio but [web deploy tools](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)

Comment: @luai-in future you need to automate this deployment process using deployment automation using MSBUILD or any other build scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot staticvoidmain , I will download this tool  and try it

Comment: You can deploy your code in local visual studio to the remote server.  Try the link above for remote deployment.  Thank you